# ¿Como crear un servicio de Windows que inicie una aplicación en c#?

Tags: c#

Como creo un servicio que lo único lo que haga sea iniciar una aplicación, así como Eset NOD, o DeepFreeze o TeamViewer que ejecutan **antes de iniciar la sesión de windows** y poder usarlo.

El servicio también verifique que si la aplicación no esté ejecutándose lo vuelva a abrir o iniciar.

He intentado crear con Servicio de Windows de Visual Studio en c#, pero al iniciar la sesión abre la aplicación o **bien no inicia** o inicia (a veces) pero pide permisos de administrador para iniciar (credenciales)

```
Public partial class MiServicio : ServiceBase
{   

  Timer tmrServicio = null;

  public MiServicio ()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    tmrServicio = new Timer (1000);
    tmrServicio.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tmrServicio_Elapsed);        
  }

  void tmrServicio_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    VerificarAppIniciar();
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
   tmrServicio.Start();
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
   tmrServicio.Stop();
  }

  void VerificarAppIniciar()
  {
        Process[] apps = Process.GetProcessesByName("sistemaventas");
        if (apps.Length == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(@"C:Archivos de programa\MiApp\sistemaventas.exe");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo no inicia la aplicación y sale este mensaje:
[image: Ventana: Detección de servicios interactivos]
No quiero que salga esta ventana sino que cargue el programa indicado.

En resumen, el servicio debe monitorear si una aplicación está ejecutándose y poder iniciarla si no está en ejecución sin pedir los credenciales o acceso de ejecución desde Windows (xp, 7, 8.1 y 10).

Comment: Aqui te dejo unos links que te pueden ayudar [Este](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite),  [Este tambien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306381/how-to-make-our-formapplication-start-running-when-windows-starts-in-c) o [Este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308011/8933039) , **los links están en ingles pero puedes traducirlo fácilmente con Google Translate**

Comment: para usar credenciales Process p = new Process("sistemaventas.exe");
p.StartInfo.UserName = "ServerAdmin";
p.StartInfo.Password = "SAPassword";
p.Start();

Comment: Hola , lograste solucionarlo? tengo el mismo problema , gracias!

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5307968/6884087) tiene varias respuestas con diferentes recomendaciones que puedes probar

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes configurar desde las propiedades del Servicio en Panel de control>Herramientas administrativas> Servicios

Busca tu servicio da clic derecho y Propiedades>Pestaña de Inicio de Sesión y usa las credenciales de tu cuenta de Administrador y al momento de ejecutar tu aplicación no debería solicitarte nuevamente las credenciales.

Comment: Ya lo quite la opción de credenciales y es automático ahora esta en modo: LocalSystem. Pero ya no se inicia la aplicación

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste utilizar una cuenta con permisos de administrador?, es decir donde te pide los datos de credenciales desde las propiedades del servicio colocar un Usuario y contraseña de alguna cuenta miembro de Administradores.

Comment: Debe iniciar sin credenciales, y si usase credenciales como ingresarlo? se supone que inicia sin credenciales para instalar en cualquier PC y con cualquier usuario de windows.